# Loading an image from assets and displaying in a dialog

Tags: java, android

I have a lot of images in the assets folder of my application that I'd like to display in a [dialog popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kJjl.png). How can I go about doing this? I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533394/icons-in-a-list-dialog?answertab=active#tab-top) covering how to display the icons, with a pretty solid answer. But in the answer, the icons are pulled from a drawable. So, I suppose I have two options:

I have taken a look at the ["Icons in a list dialog" thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533394/icons-in-a-list-dialog) but the answer posted uses drawables. I don't have a drawable for every single image because I have over 250 images.

Then I saw the ["load drawable from assets"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884882/is-it-possible-to-load-a-drawable-from-the-assets-folder) thread, but that doesn't quite get me there either. The "icons in a list dialog" expects a specific r.drawable.drawablename.

This is currently how I display the countries text:

```
public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FtC_Setup.this);
     builder.setTitle("Standard countries");
     final CharSequence[] items = FtC_Play.allCountries.toArray(new CharSequence[FtC_Play.allCountries.size()]);
     builder.setItems(items, null).show(); 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to load a drawable from the assets folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884882/is-it-possible-to-load-a-drawable-from-the-assets-folder)

Comment: I saw that question. But I don't know what to do once it is loaded - how do I display it?

Comment: Also, that is loading a drawable. I am just loading a .gif, which I need to convert and then be able to display.